# Is there a Java/JUnit version of NUnit annotation [TestFixture]

Tags: java, c#, junit, nunit

I am starting to write WebDriver tests in Java having previously used C#/NUnit. I notice in any examples I have seen there is no Java version of the C# NUnit annotation for [TestFixture]. Is there such a thing in Java?

Comment: What does that thing do? Most of the people familiar with Java testing don't know NUnit.

Comment: Not sure if they exist in Java but `[TestFixture]` is an attribute. Essentialy metadata in your code, in this case you decorate the class definition with this and it tells NUnit that this class contains unit tests.

Comment: JUnit at least has the equivalents of NUnit's `[TestFixtureSetUp]` and `[SetUp]`: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-fixtures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent annotation to `[TestFixture]` in JUnit. Classes with methods marked with `@Test` get run by most JUnit test runners without any other special markings; and `@Before` methods act like `[SetUp]`; and `@After` methods act like `[TearDown]`.